# OPENSSL by Cavium

Tags: openssl, openssl-engine

Cavium provides a configured OPENSSL for better performance on their hardware. It usage must lowers the CPU utilization by crypto operations offloading. I wanted to ask whether we can install Cavium OPENSSL Toolkit on Linux OS (on Cavium hardware), just as we install a standard OPENSSL? OR the only way to use this Cavium OPENSSL is by making simple executive application/user space and use the provided OPENSSL as an API.

Please guide and share any details (readme, tutorial, link etc) regarding Cavium OPENSSL.

Regards

Comment: It would probably be easier to get a diff of Cavium changes to OpenSSL, and then apply them to your Linux machine running on the Cavium hardware. I don't know how easy/hard it is to get the diff of OpenSSL (it could be nearly impossible if they don't share it).

Comment: Also see OpenSSL RT [Issue 3773: PATCH: Configure support for OCTEON boards](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3773&user=guest&pass=guest). But it seems to lack specialization of the code; instead it only provides a configure line.

Comment: taking diff can be a good starting point.